# adding and substacting index in java

Tags: java, loops

I'm new in Java and need an explanation how this works... I know it's really basic, but I struggle to understand it! :)

```
  int qty[] = new int[5];

  for (int i = 0; i < qty.length; i++)

     qty[i] = i+1;

  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)

     qty[j+1] += qty[j];


  for (int i = 0; i < qty.length; i++)

     System.out.print(" " + qty[i]);
     System.out.println();
```

Why the result is 1,3,6,10,15? I'm trying to understand, but I can't. How does this inner loop iterates? How does it get to 10 and 15?

thanks, guys!

Comment: Try unrolling the loops in a piece of paper, after a few iterations you should get the gist of what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
After initial:   
    1 
    2
    3
    4
    5

During j loop:
1 -> 1
2 -> 2+1  -> 3
3 -> 3+3  -> 6
4 -> 4+6  -> 10
5 -> 5+10 -> 15
```

The j loop starts on position j+1, looks at the element inside it, sums it with the element @j and overwrites the value. Looks at the next element, sums it with the element @j. And so on

Answer (score 1):

First thing you have to understand is how the code is executed when you do not have curly braces in your code, that is { and }.
The immediate code line after the conditional statement in your code belongs to the loop execution. Therefore, you can think of your code in the way shown below as well.

```
// array to hold 5 integers are created 
int qty[] = new int[5];


for (int i = 0; i < qty.length; i++){
     qty[i] = i+1;
}
//after the above iteration, the array becomes {1,2,3,4,5}

for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
     qty[j+1] += qty[j];
}
//after the above iteration, the array becomes {1,3,6,10,15}

for (int i = 0; i < qty.length; i++){
     System.out.print(" " + qty[i]);
}
//now it'll print  1 3 6 10 15

     System.out.println();
```

Comment: Wow, guys, you are heroes! :) This is more than helpful. I was struggling to understand the core of it. Beautiful! Thanks agaian! :)